# Tomcat: Possible to run a single App instance on Multiple

Tags: tomcat

In TomCat, is it possible to run a single instance of an app on two different arbitrary ports (e.g. 8445, 8446)?

Answer (score 1):

You can put in multiple `<Connector>` elements. See [the docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) on the HTTP connector. Also, you can copy the existing Connector and just modify the port number.